# Synchronizing Multiple Views, Editors & Commit/Cancel

Tags: c#, architecture, mvvm, synchronization, editor

We're thinking about an architecture to support multiple views and editors on the same object. A requirement is the possibility to commit or cancel the changes done on a whole object.

Our requirements are
- lot's of objects edited at the same time (up to 10.000 in multiselect mode)
- multiple views and editors at the same time
- changes in on editor on the object should only reflect in the other views after a succesful commit
- the objects in an editor should be committable/cancellable as a whole

We've had a look at several concepts, including the dynamic-wrapper approach (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dynamicobjectproxy.aspx#EditableProxy%28implementingIEditableObject%299), which we've discarded because of 
- no Intellisense on dynamics
- no compile time checks on dynamics
- access on the properties when iterating over them (e.g. for property grids) is very expensive

We've implemented a prototype of architectur in the figure

each editor gets its own clone of the original object. it can then work on it, validate it and commit it into the imodelrepository. when doing that, the original object gets updated and a backendchanged event gets sent out for each clone. The viewmodels of the other editors registered for the backendchanged events and now get new clones to reflect the changes

the positive aspects are:
- the imodelrepository only outputs clones, a direct editing of the original is prohibited
- each editor can work on it's own clone
- there is a way to notify the other clones and update there content if one editor commits a change
but the negative aspects are:
- each editor/Viewer viewmodel has to look for a backendchanged object that gets sent if the original objects gets changed. it then needs to get a new clone and discard the old one
- additionally each editor/viewer has to look for a object deleted event, if another editor deleted the object. it then needs to discard its clone
- a lot of clones is needed, which slows down the system, especially for a large number on edited objects at the same time

we're thinking about handing the original to viewmodels registered as viewers only, and using the clones for the real editors. That would cut down the number of clones needed. But there is no way to ensure a readonly original for the viewers (dynamic readonly wrapper causes the same problems as the editableproxy mentioned above)

i would be thankful for any input or ideas as how to simplify the approach, or about a different architecture

thx

[image: Synchronizing multiple Views]

Comment: Are the editors used by same user/machine or are they remote. How fast do you want the changes to be reflected? - Every field change or commits only?

Comment: The Editors are all on the same machine. It is enough for our system to reflect changes on commits only.

Comment: Would reflecting changes immediately and removing commit do too (with undo option)?

Comment: The commit option is something that our pm explicitly wished, i don't think that they want to drop that. Additionally while editing the edited object may be in an invalid state (we're using the IDataErrorInfo concept to propagate validation changes), and the user should only be able to commit it to the database if it's in a valid state. But any approaches are welcome, if you've got a link or idea, please tell, perhaps we can use parts of it for the solution. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If multiple editors above same model object can be opened simultaneously,
  then waiting for commit to update the others would be counter intuitive(*),
  in this case I'd use the same VM for them all and let them edit the object in its intermediate states too and use a global commit that updates the repository from VM's changes.
- If multiple editors above same model object can NOT be opened simultaneously,
  then one VM (per model object) at a time should do.
  You could use T4s to generate a readonly VM class for viewers, that is identical to the original VM class, just without property setters.

(*) E.g. use could update a name, other viewers/editors would still show old name, user could edit name to two different values in two different editors without committing.
If one editors changes are committed, changes in other editor may be lost during recloning.

- Another approach is to have one readonly VM for all viewers (can be T4 generated from editor's VM),
  allow multiple editors to update same model object, use timestamp based concurrency (optimistic concurrency) in repository, and continue giving a seperate VM to each editor.
  Changes will be feed to repository on commits, already open editors will not be aware of changes until they try to commit.
  When they try to commit, if model object has been edited, a exception will be thrown (e.g. OptimisticConcurrencyException in EF), which you can catch to enable user to react to (disgard, overwrite, merge).

Comment: thanks for your input. i'll look into t4 code generation asap, we didn't have anything to do with it until now. Since we cannot guarantee that there is only one editor open per object, your second approach may be the one for us to go.